# Can user with "Member" role upload binaries to AppStore for test?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Can user with "Member" role upload builds for test? I tried to do it but got this:
   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that only users with the Admin, Technical, or App Manager role can submit apps for review

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)